# auto complete extender not working in PHP 

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

this auto complete extender is working perfectly but i dont whats the reason its stopped working , No javascript error is coming .Here is my code

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({   
      source: "searchEAN.php",
      minLength: 2,//search after two characters
      select: function(event,ui){
       // alert ($value.$id);
       alert (ui.item.value);
      //do something, like search for your hotel detail page
      }  
    });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">
  <div class="ui-widget">
     <label for="autocomplete">Hotel Name: </label>
     <input id="autocomplete" name="autocomplete"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is `searchEAN.php` page code . its return data when i run this page directly by passing terms as query string

```
<?php

include_once('config.php');

if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends    
$qstring = "SELECT Distinct CONCAT(City,',',StateProvince,',',Country) AS value,EANHotelID AS id FROM ActivePropertyList WHERE City LIKE '%".$term."%' GROUP BY value limit 0,10 ";
echo $qstring;
$result = mysql_query($qstring);//query the database for entries containing the term

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))//loop through the retrieved values
{
     $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
     $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
     $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
mysql_close();
}


?>
```

[searchEAN.php](http://sayhotel.com/rahul/searchEAN.php?term=london) can be check here .live link and auto complete which is not working can be check [here](http://sayhotel.com/rahul/index.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- your `echo $qstring;` is in your `PHP` script. Comment it out!

Comment: @lorga yes i also find that just after putting the question here. thanks for your time. I will accept your answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry , Problem solved that is mine mistake , I echo the query to check it but forgot to comment it. thats the reason its no working .

I comment out the

```
//echo $qstring; in searchEAN.php file
```

and its working now

thanks